# New line cause a "\par" even the "\endlinechar" is changed to "\char256" in TeX

Tags: tex-core, characters

TeX will insert `\endlinechar` at the end of line.

> If the value of `\endlinechar` is negative or greater than 255, no character is appended, and the effect is as if every line ends with %.

```
\def\endlinechar{\char256}
hello

hello2
\bye
```

produces

[image]

Even if the `\endlinechar` has been changed to greater than 255, the character is still append to the end of the line, which cause the effect as `\par` at the end of the line. What is the reason?

Comment: You've not set `\endlinechar`-the-primitive, you've created a macro of the same name: you want `\endlinechar=256 %`

Comment: @JosephWright What is the meaning of `\endlinechar=256`.  From what page I should watch to learn this style of definition?

Comment: The primitive integer parameters are listed on pp. 272-273.

Comment: @campa God.This book has such a big jump.

Comment: @Y.zeng As we've said many times, you need to read the book several times and skip over the harder parts until you are comfortable

Comment: @JosephWright I'm a little reluctant to not be able to read in a straight line.

Comment: But when you are reading TeXbook in a straight line then it is almost unreadable for you (as we can see here).

Comment: @wipet Yes. Maybe I need to change my tactic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\endlinechar` is an internal integer register. Assigning it a value is done in the standard way, namely

```
\endlinechar=<integer>
```

just like

```
\count255=42
```

In Knuth TeX or `pdftex` you can assign it the value 256, which would result in nothing being appended to a record after discarding the OS specific end-of-record signal and trailing characters with ASCII code 32.

If you do `\def\endlinechar{whatever}`, you just lose the ability to change the value of the internal register.

**Note.** XeTeX behaves like Knuth TeX as far as `\endlinechar` is concerned, so only values between 0 and 255 (inclusive) will result in some character being appended. LuaTeX lowers the upper bound to 127.

You should have been surprised that the code doesn't raise errors. Indeed, your `\endlinechar` *macro* is never used, otherwise `\char256` would have raised an error (in Knuth TeX or `pdftex`).